# Convert strings representing unit of time or distance to numeric

Tags: r, string-parsing

I would like to search a data.frame column with string distances and convert them to numeric fields. I would do the same on twitter style dates such as '3 days ago' using the same function.

If I was starting with:

```
x <- c("5 days ago", "1 day ago", "6 days ago")
```

I would end up with:

```
x <- c(120, 24, 144)
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Do you have always the same unit, so that you only need to extract numbers or do units vary? I.e., is your example representative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data consist  only "number days ago" or "number miles" you can use regular expressions:

```
> x <- c("5 days ago", "1 day ago", "6 days ago", "21.2 miles", "1 mile")
> x[grep(" day",x)] <- as.numeric(gsub("[ daysago]","",x[grep(" day",x)] ))*24
> x
[1] "120"        "24"         "144"        "21.2 miles" "1 mile"    
> x[grep(" mile",x)] <- as.numeric(gsub("[ miles]","",x[grep(" mile",x)] )) 
> x
[1] "120"  "24"   "144"  "21.2" "1"   
> x <- as.numeric(x)
> x
[1] 120.0  24.0 144.0  21.2   1.0
```

Comment: This solution allows for the regex grouping with the grep command. In my case the `regmatches(strLine, gregexpr('\\(?[0-9]+', strLine))` @Eldar wrote was more useful to thow out averything but the digits, but can definitely see the need for gsub in similar circumstances.

Comment: The code I used just changed gsub to strip everything but the number. `x[grep("day",x)] <- as.numeric(gsub("[[:alpha:]|[:blank:]]","",x[grep("day",x)] )) * 24`

Answer (score 1):

Check `stringr` library and `str_extract_all` function

```
x <- c("5 days ago", "1 day ago", "6 days ago")
library(stringr)
x <- 24*as.numeric(str_extract_all(x, "\\d"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
strLine <- c("5 days ago", "1 day ago", "6 days ago")
x <- as.numeric(unlist(regmatches(strLine, gregexpr('\\(?[0-9]+', strLine)))) * 24
x
# [1] 120  24 144
```